# Acceso a los datos con C# NetCore relacion de muchos a muchos con Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#

tengo la siguiente duda con respecto a las relaciones N a N en Entity Framework Code First con NetCore (c#)

Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class Playlist
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPlaylist { get; set; }
    public List<Audio> Audios { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Audio
{
    [Key]
    public int IdAudio { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    ...
}
  
public class AudioPlaylist
{
            
    public int IdAudio { get; set; }               
    public int IdPlaylist { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdPlaylist")]
    public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdAudio")]
    public Audio Audio { get; set; }
}
```

Mi duda es cuando accedo a estos datos, tengo una capa de manejo a la bd, donde tengo el manejador de Audio con sus funciones y el manejador de playlist con sus funciones.

Es necesario tener un manejador para la relación AudioPlaylist o con hacer en Playlist un Include (x => x.Audios) alcanzaría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario traerte una entidad y luego la otra, además es una mala aproximación. Con el include te hace el inner en BBDD y te trae la relación por la foránea. Si quieres updatear o añadir un objeto nuevo a una colección de una relación 1 a N también lo puedes hacer a través del contexto. El modelo de repositorios es una buena aproximación, dependiendo de la arquitectura base que utilices.
Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo @D3vid con un Include seria suficiente, pero podrias utilizar `HashSet` para cargar la lista de las tablas donde tienes una llave foreanea.

por ejemplo:

```
public class Audio
{
    public Audio()
    {
       AudioPlaylists = new HashSet<AudioPlaylist>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int IdAudio { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AudioPlaylist> AudioPlaylists { get; set; }
}
```

Esto lo he configurado con Fluent, desconozco si con anotaciones se comporta igual.